# Javascript library for dockable panels/tabs?

Tags: javascript, layout, widget, panel

In the process of converting a .NET rich application to Javascript.  One of the GUI features folks liked a lot was to rearrange their application layout.  In .NET this was accomplished via Sandock:

http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sanddock/screenshots.aspx

Anything like this for Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813511/docking-window-framework-written-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

The closest I know to that is the javascript library [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/). I've used it in a few projects very successfully since it allows you to create rich Web UIs very similar to windows UIs (or widgets).

The learning curve can be a bit steep though if you aren't that familiar with javascript, however the community is quick to respond and helpful.

Comment: Thanks -- they have a demo of a "portal" that is very close to what I need.  http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/portal/portal.html

Answer (score 6):

If ExtJS is not your cup of tea, there is a rather nice jquery port of the same concept.

Demos here: 
http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm (particularly [this](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html))

Answer (score 3):

I needed this very thing, and did not find any to my liking so I decided to write my own.  It is almost complete, but you can check it out here:

Edit: Still being developed actively, but fully functional now.

http://docker.webcabin.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a javascript dock panel implmentation, I just created one myself. You can find it at https://github.com/developerDoug/HtmlJavascriptDockInVS2010