# Javascript framework for creating panel-based layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a small online IDE (Inspired by Cloud9 IDE) as a hobby project, but i'm struggling with the layout. I started using Twitter Bootstrap, but it's impossible to have dockable panels (sidebar, footer, etc.). So, i'm looking for a Javascript-based framework, or even a modern CSS framework, that allows me to have a layout with dockable panels and so on. Similar to this:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5tS6.png

I was able to find this jQuery plugin: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm
But it seems to be obsolete and very bloated. Is there anything similar out there?

UPDATE:
**I'm not looking for an ExtJS alternative. I don't need widgets, datagrids or anything. I just need a flexible layout framework, which allows me to dock those layouts.**

Comment: Check out Ext JS, the layout system is quite fully featured.

Comment: I'm looking for something simpler, that allows me to use pure HTML & JS, and my own CSS. ExtJS, Capuccino and others are not really a choice.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate question of [Javascript library for dockable panels/tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208382/javascript-library-for-dockable-panels-tabs) and take a look at this [ExtJS based demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/portal/portal.html)

Comment: Not, not really. I'm not looking for an ExtJS alternative. I don't need widgets, datagrids or anything. I just need a flexible layout framework, which allows me to dock those layouts.

Comment: I also found this interesting blog post titled [Advanced docking using jQuery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/advanced-docking-using-jquery/) where it uses jQuery.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of frameworks as you have done here are off-topic. For it to be on-topic, you'll have to phrase your question ask not for frameworks but how to do it in general. From there, if someone feels a framework is appropriate, they will answer with one, but if a different solution is more appropriate, that can be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically achieved through `position: absolute`. Say you have a container with a panel docked on the side and a panel in the middle:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="side-panel">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="middle-panel">
        <1-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If `side-panel` was to be 200 pixels wide, this would suffice:

```
.side-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
.middle-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
}
```

`top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` specify the distance between that edge of the element and its container.<sup>1</sup> It turns out that you can nest these, too. Put this together and you can have a rather sophisticated fixed panel-based layout.

Of course, you probably want to dynamically adjust the panels. To do that, you'll need to write some JavaScript to set the `style` dynamically. To rearrange the whole layout of the page, you'll need to go beyond setting `style`s and move elements in the DOM around.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Actually the nearest non-`static`ally-positioned element.